# Passing values to another component

Tags: angular, typescript, components

So i have this program in angular where so far i take in a zip code from a user and on button click it sends that input to a function where it is sent off to an api to convert into Lat & Long coordinates. see below:

**home.component.html**

```
<div class="center" style="margin-top:50px;">
        <label for="ZipCode"><b>Zip Code</b></label>        
    </div>

    <div class="center">
        <input name="zipcode" #zipcode id="zipcode" type="text" placeholder="Enter Zip Code" maxlength="5">
    </div>
<div class="center" style="margin-top:100px;">
        <button class="button button1" (click)="getCoords(zipcode.value)" ><b>Retrieve Data</b></button>
    </div>
```

clearly this is only a snippet of the code but it is enough for display purposes. next is the function with api and it then shifts the view to the stations component/page:

**home.component.ts**

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    
    constructor(
        private router: Router
    ){}

    ngOnInit(): void {
    }

    getCoords(val: any){
        var url = "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=MYKEY&location=" + val;

        fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            var lat = data.results[0].locations[0].displayLatLng.lat;
            var long = data.results[0].locations[0].displayLatLng.lng;

            this.router.navigate(["/stations"])
        })        
    }
}
```

**stations.component.ts** - as you can see nothing here yet because i cant figure out what to do

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-stations',
  templateUrl: './stations.component.html'
})

export class StationsComponent implements OnInit {
  

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

now this all works correctly. i have tested the lat and long variables in the console-log and it returns the lat and long just fine. my problem is i need to send the lat and long value to another component/page to be used in calculations. i wont lie by saying i have scoured the internet trying to find a way to do so but apparently it isnt easy in angular to do so. anyone have any ideas on passing the lat and long value to another component/page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use query parameter handling like bellow code ↓

```
   getCoords(val: any){
        var url = "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=MYKEY&location=" + val;

        fetch(url)
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
            var lat = data.results[0].locations[0].displayLatLng.lat;
            var long = data.results[0].locations[0].displayLatLng.lng;

            this.router.navigate(["/stations"], {queryParams :{ dataLat : lat, dataLong : long}} )
        })        
    }
```

and in your stations.component.ts you can use ActivatedRoute to get the data:

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-stations',
  templateUrl: './stations.component.html'
})

export class StationsComponent implements OnInit {
  
  getLat:any;
  getLong:any;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      this.getLat = params.dataLat;
      this.getLong = params.dataLong;
      console.log(params); 
    });
  }
}
```

and you can learn more about that here [guide router](https://angular.io/guide/router) and [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-query-parameters)

Comment: i get some squigglys under the ```dataLat: lat``` and the error says:
`Argument of type '{ dataLat: any; dataLong: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NavigationExtras'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'dataLat' does not exist in type 'NavigationExtras'.`

Comment: nvm i used the links you gave to add `queryParams:` to the inside of the `this.router.navigate(["/stations"], {queryParams: { dataLat : lat, dataLong : long}})` and now it works. thank you so much!! youve been amazing!!

Comment: gald i can help, I update the answer.

Comment: and can you click the accept answer button :)

Comment: sorry about that. still new to SO. its done :) thanks again!!